# Gradle build throws error but runs successfully when executed after locking dependencies

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, build, gradlew

I am developing a Kotlin project using gradlew on IntelliJ. When I build the project using `gradlew build`, I receive an `unresolved reference` error for a dependency. When I lock the dependencies, the dependency shows up in the `build.lock` file, and then the build executes smoothly.

I do not find this entirely strange but I do not know the exact reason(s) of its occurrence.

What could be the possible cause(s) for this? Could it be that during direct build execution, when the compilation process reaches the file where the dependency error is thrown, the dependency might not be available then, and it becomes available later during the compile process?

I would greatly appreciate any references that would help me understand the process better in this context for both build and lockdown commands.

Many Thanks!